# Soma total com vários valores de forma dinâmica usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, soma

Estou tentando fazer uma função que pegue os valores de todas `<div class="preco-produto">` faça a soma total e popule na `<div id="final">`.

Fiz a função que separa o valor número do *String* da `div`, mas não estou conseguindo fazer com que a apresentação do total seja dinâmico.

Preciso que sempre que o valor de cada campo `<div class="preco-produto">` seja alterado, diretamente o do `<div id="final">` também seja, fazendo um calculo automático.

Lembrando que, sempre que o usuário clica no botão "Add", é criada outra `div` com os mesmos campos da primeira, ou seja, pode haver vários `<div class="preco-produto">`. Alguém consegue me dar uma luz de como posso mudar meu código para que isso ocorra ?

index.php:

```
<div id="allProducts">
                <div class="produtos-wrap"> <!---- DIV A SER CLONADA / ADICIONADA !---->
                    <div class=" text-center select_height">
                        <b>Número:</b>
                        <div class="index" class="font-pop">1</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center select_height">
                        <b>ID:</b>
                        <div class="font-pop number_id_produto">0</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class=" select_height">
                        <b>Selecione um produto:</b>
                        <select class="selectpicker form-control teste" data-show-subtext="false"
                                data-live-search="true" name="select_produtos[]" onchange="initProdutos(this)">
                            <?php
                            foreach ($result2 as $item_produtos) {
                                echo '<option data-subtext="' . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '" value="'
                                    . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '">' . $item_produtos['desc_produto'] . '</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center select_height">
                        <b>Embalagem:</b>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="2" class="edit-input font-pop" name="embalagem[]" value="">
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center select_height">
                        <b>Preço:</b>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="5" name="preco[]" class="edit-input font-pop" value="0">
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center select_height">
                        <b>Quantidade:</b>
                        <br>
                        <input type="text" maxlength="3" class="edit-input font-pop" value="0"
                               name="quantidade-produto[]">
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center select_height">
                        <b>Preço do Produto:</b>
                        <div class="font-pop preco-produto" onchange="split()">R$ 0</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center select_height">
                        <button class="remover">X</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button id="add-button" onclick="">+</button>
        </div>

        <div class="container" id="produto-total">
            <div class="assinatura col-lg-6">
                Assinatura
            </div>

            <div class="preco-final col-lg-6">
                <b>Preço total:</b>
                <div id="total"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JQuery:

```
function initProdutos(e) {
    var wraper = $(e).closest(".produtos-wrap"); // pega a div principal
    var letras_produtos = $(e).val()
    const $preco = $("[name='preco[]']", wraper);
    const $qtd = $("[name='quantidade-produto[]']", wraper);
    const $total = $(".preco-produto", wraper);
    const $final = $('#total');

    function recalculate() {
        const total = Number($preco.val() || 0) * Number($qtd.val() || 0);
        $total.text("R$ " + total);
    }

    function sub(){
        $($preco).on('change',function () {
            var sub = $(this).val().replace(',', '.');
            $(this).val(sub);
        })
    }

    function split(){
        $($total).each(function () {
            var str = $(this).html();
            var res = str.split(" ");
            $($final).text(res[1]);
        })
    }

    function total(){
        $('.preco-produto div').on('change',function () {
            var t = 0;
            $('.preco-produto').each(function (i,e) {
                if ($(e).val()){
                    if (isNaN(i)) {$(e).val(''); return; }
                    t += parseFloat(i);
                    $($final).text('R$ ' + t.toFixed(2));
                }
            })
        })
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "API.php",
        data: {
            "mode": "produtos", letras_produtos
        },
        dataType: "JSON",
        //CASO DÊ TUDO CERTO
        success: function (data) {
            $('[name="embalagem[]"]', wraper).val(data[0]['embalagem']);
            $('.number_id_produto', wraper).text(data[0]['id_produto']);
            recalculate();
            sub();
            total();
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
    $preco.on('input', recalculate, sub());
    $qtd.on('input', recalculate);
    $total.on('div',split(),total());
    $final.on('div',split(),total());
    recalculate();
    sub();
    split();
    total();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa criar um *event handler* para os campos de preço e quantidade usando o evento `input` (esse evento é disparado em tempo real sempre que você alterar os campos).

Crie também uma função separada para formatar o valor no formato "R$ X,XX" usando `.toLocaleString()`.

E crie outra função para fazer o cálculo geral (`calculos()`). Essa função você irá chamar também quando remover uma div da lista.

No *event handler* você irá percorrer todos os elementos com a classe `.preco-produto` e ir somando os valores. Basta inserir o código abaixo (com comentários explicativos):

```
function calculos(){
   // variável do total
   var total = 0;
   // soma tudo e coloca na div do total
   $(".preco-produto").each(function(){
      // pega apenas o valor e ignora o "R$", remove o ponto e substitui vírgula por ponto
      var p = parseFloat($(this).text().match(/[\d|,|\.]+/)[0].replace(".", "").replace(",", "."));
      total += p;
   });
   // coloca o valor total na div "total"
   $("#total").text(formataMoeda(total));
}

$(document).on("input", "[name='preco[]'], [name='quantidade-produto[]']", function(){
   // pega a div principal
   var wraper = $(this).closest(".produtos-wrap");
   // pega a quantidade   
   var qtd_produto = $("[name='quantidade-produto[]']", wraper).val();
   // pega o preço
   var preco_produto = $("[name='preco[]']", wraper).val().replace(",", ".");
   // div com o valor do produto
   var total_produto = $(".preco-produto", wraper);
   // coloca o valor total do produto
   total_produto.text(formataMoeda(qtd_produto * preco_produto));
   calculos(); // chama a função para calcular o total geral
});

// função para formatar a moeda em Real
function formataMoeda(v){
   return v.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' });
}
```

Comment: Sam, ele está dando um erro na função do '.toLocaleString', seria que coloquei seu código no lugar errado ou algo do tipo ? No console está aparecendo assim:

https://prnt.sc/o1wroo ,

https://prnt.sc/o1wrxa

Comment: Seria melhor eu mudar o elemento '.preco-produto' de DIV para um input ? Ou não terá nenhum problema futuro ?

Comment: A função de formatar a moeda tem que ter um valor. Veja que vc só colocou formataMoeda() sem um valor.

Comment: Deixar como div não tem problema algum, é até melhor porque é um elemento apenas ilustrativo para mostrar o valor.

Comment: Consegui arrumar esta questão, agora ocorre que, sempre que eu removo alguma DIV que estava com seu valor somado no "Total", este valor não é subtraído do valor Total. Como posso fazer essa questão ?

Comment: Alterei a resposta. Basta chamar a função `calculos()` no final da função que remove um item da lista.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado Sam. Você teria uma indicação de algum material ou algo de tipo para eu me aprofundar no estudo em JQuery / Javascript ?

Comment: W3 Schools é um bom lugar pra começar.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pela dica e pela ajuda Sam, agradeço de coração !

Comment: Sam, Desculpe o incomodo, mas gostaria de tirar uma dúvida com você a respeito de um bug que está ocorrendo com este código. Se o valor do produto por um valor decimal, no Total ele não lê, e se a quantidade do produto for maior que 100, o Total também buga. O que pode estar ocorrendo ?

Print's: https://prnt.sc/o2wbuf  ,  https://prnt.sc/o2wc2n

Comment: Apenas corrigindo, se o preço do Produto passa do valor de R$999, o preço Total já buga.

Comment: Opa! Blz? Substitua esta linha: `var p = parseFloat($(this).text().match(/[\d|,|\.]+/)[0].replace(".", "").replace(",", "."));`

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado Sam !

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando escutar eventos que não existem em `div`. Os eventos devem ser escutados diretamente nos botões e inputs do seu carrinho.

Veja o exemplo abaixo e tente adaptá-lo para sua necessidade.

```js
var produtos = [
  {codigo: '001', nome: "Arroz", valor: 1.99},
  {codigo: '002', nome: "Feijão", valor: 12.25},
  {codigo: '003', nome: "Ovo", valor: 6.11},
  {codigo: '004', nome: "Farinha", valor: 7.07},
];

produtos.forEach(function (item) {
  $('<option />')
    .attr('value', item.codigo)
    .text(`${item.nome} - R$ ${item.valor}`)
    .appendTo('#produtos');
});

$(document).on('click', '#btn-add', function () {
  var $dropdown = $('#produtos'), codigo = $dropdown.val();
  
  // 1. Se dropdown não possui nenhum item selecionado nao faça nada
  if (!codigo.length) return;
  
  // obter o item pelo codigo
  var item = getProdutoByCodigo(produtos, codigo);
  
  // 2. Se item selecionado já está no carrinho, 
  // incrementar a quantidade se nao tiver adiciona-lo
  if (!$(`tr#${item.codigo}`).length) addProduto(item);
  else incrementarQuantidade(item);
  
  atualizarTotal();
});

$(document).on('change', '.field-qtd', function () {
  var $this = $(this), 
      item = getProdutoByCodigo(produtos, $this.data('codigo')), 
      qtd = $this.val(),
      subTotal = (qtd * item.valor).toFixed(2);
  
  $this.parents('tr').find('.subtotal').text(`R$ ${subTotal}`);
  atualizarTotal();
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn-remover', function () {
  $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  atualizarTotal();
});

function getProdutoByCodigo(produtos, codigo) {
  return produtos.filter(produto => produto.codigo === codigo)[0];
}

function createDropdownQuantidade(item) {
  var $dropdown = $('<select />')
    .attr({name: 'quantidade'})
    .addClass('form-control field-qtd')
    .data('codigo', item.codigo);
    
   for (var i = 1; i < 100; i ++) {
    $('<option />').attr('value', i).text(i).appendTo($dropdown);
   }
   
   return $dropdown;
}

function addProduto(item) {  
  var $tr = $('<tr />').attr('id', item.codigo);
  $('<td />').text(item.codigo).appendTo($tr);
  $('<td />').text(item.nome).appendTo($tr);
  $('<td />').append(createDropdownQuantidade(item)).appendTo($tr);  
  $('<td />').text(`R$ ${item.valor.toFixed(2)}`).appendTo($tr);
  $('<td />').addClass('subtotal').text(`R$ ${item.valor.toFixed(2)}`).appendTo($tr);
  
  var $button = $('<button />')
    .addClass('btn btn-danger btn-remover')
    .html('&times;')
    .attr('title', 'Remover');
    
  $('<td />').append($button).appendTo($tr);
  
  $tr.appendTo('#cart-body');
}

function incrementarQuantidade(item) {
  var $dropdown = $(`tr#${item.codigo}`).find('select'), qtd = $dropdown.val();
  $dropdown.val(++qtd).trigger('change');
}

function atualizarTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $('#cart-body').find('tr').each(function () {
    var codigo = $(this).attr('id'), 
        qtd = $(this).find('.field-qtd').val(), 
        item = getProdutoByCodigo(produtos, codigo);
  
    total += (qtd * item.valor);
  });
    
  $('.total').text(`R$ ${total.toFixed(2)}`);
}
```

```css
.field-qtd {max-width: 100px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="form-inline my-3">
 <select name="produtos" id="produtos" class="form-control">
  <option value="">- Selecione -</option>
 </select>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary ml-2" id="btn-add">Add</button>
</div>

<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <th>Código</th>
    <th>Produto</th>
    <th>Qtd</th>
    <th>Preço unitário</th>
    <th>Subtotal</th>
    <th>Remover</th>
  </thead>
 
  <tbody id="cart-body"></tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" class="text-right text-uppercase border-top">total</td>
      <td class="total border-top">R$ 0.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
<table>
```